# Xcode Simulator Download Issue: Non-Resumable Downloads Consuming Data

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

My Xcode recently updated to the latest version, and I encountered an issue where, when attempting to run my Flutter app on a simulator, the simulator launches without a user interface.

To resolve this, I launched Xcode to download the latest iOS 17 simulator. However, I'm facing a problem: it appears that the download process is not resumable, which is causing excessive data consumption.

I'm currently in an area with a weak network connection, and the simulator download size is approximately 7.56GB. Whenever I close my laptop and later attempt to resume the download, it fails, and I can't continue from where it left off.

I'm puzzled by why Apple designed the download process this way. Why isn't it possible to make the download resumable?

I'm curious if anyone else has experienced this issue or if I'm the only one facing this problem.