# iOS Simulator: Resumable Download Method and Xcode Integration

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there an alternative method for downloading the latest iOS simulator in a resumable manner outside of Xcode, and how can I configure Xcode to recognize and use it? I previously sought opinions on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220945/xcode-simulator-download-issue-non-resumable-downloads-consuming-data), but haven't received any responses thus far.